# Verify BigQuery table existence

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I have a simple function to determine whether a table exists or not:

```
def check_users_usersmetadata_existence():
    """
    Checks if the table Prod_UserUserMetadata exists
    """
    app_id = get_app_id()
    bigquery_client = bigquery.Client(project=app_id)
    dataset_ref = bigquery_client.dataset('Backup')
    table_ref = dataset_ref.table('Prod_UserUserMetadata')
    try:
        table = bigquery_client.get_table(table_ref)
        if table:
            print('Table {}\'s existence sucessfully proved!'.format(table_ref))
            return True
    except HttpError as error:
        raise
        print('Whoops! Table {} doesn\'t exist here! Ref: {}'.format(table_ref, error.resp.status))
        return False
```

Problem is, it throws a 404 on this line `table = bigquery_client.get_table(table_ref)` which is ok because the table shouldn't exist. But it won't continue to process the rest of the script. I'm trying to parse it inside a `try except` wrapper however it's not working. How would I parse this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your script is not entering the exception clause as it raises a `NotFound` error and not a `HttpError`.

This should work:

```
from google.cloud.exceptions import NotFound
def check_users_usersmetadata_existence():
    # (...)
    try:
        table = bigquery_client.get_table(table_ref)
        if table:
            print('Table {}\'s existence sucessfully proved!'.format(table_ref))
            return True
    except NotFound as error:
        # ...do some processing ...
        print('Whoops! Table {} doesn\'t exist here! Ref: {}'.format(table_ref, error.resp.status))
        return False
```

Comment: Still throws `11:49:47.607
NotFound: 404 GET https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/liu-laureateid-api-qa/datasets/Backup/tables/Prod_UserUserMetadata: Not found: Table liu-laureateid-api-qa:Backup.Prod_UserUserMetadata`

Comment: hmm this is weird. Just ran the same code here and it worked. Have you confirmed that your script is getting inside the exception clause? Is it printing the 'whoops' message?

Comment: notice also that I removed the `raise`, if you keep it there it will break from the function and raise with the error message.

Answer (score 3):

See the example in the official documentation of the BigQuery Python client: https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/usage/tables.html#getting-a-table

Excerpt:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud.exceptions import NotFound

client = bigquery.Client()
# table_id = "your-project.your_dataset.your_table"

try:
    client.get_table(table_id)  # Make an API request.
    print("Table {} already exists.".format(table_id))
except NotFound:
    print("Table {} is not found.".format(table_id))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using except NotFound
NotFound is defined in https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/blob/release-core-1.3.0/api_core/google/api_core/exceptions.py#L219